# What drove the development the free group and free products of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, math-history

In my modern algebra class, we've motivated the construction of the free group and free product of groups using basic category theory - that is, the discussion was framed for our purposes as a search for free objects and coproducts in the category of groups. However, category theory is a pretty modern development in mathematics and the free group and free product were around before the general notions of free objects, coproducts, and universal products. What motivated the construction of these objects in the first place?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#History

Comment: My guess is that historically the motivation went the other way around: the concept of free groups (and other "free" constructions to follow) drove the abstract concept of free objects in category theory.

Comment: That makes sense, but what drove the need for those objects in the first place? The wiki link is somewhat helpful with regards to the free group, but I'm still not sure what created the need for the free product.